# VueJS CLI function not available

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2

i'm new to VueJS CLI webpack.
I want to globally include my javascript files.

my main.js:

```
require('./assets/css/main.css');

require('./assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js');
require('./assets/js/vendor/TweenMax.min.js');
require('./assets/js/vendor/device.min.js');

require('./assets/js/functions.js');
```

In **functions.js** i'm using functions from all of the libraries(jquery,device.js...)

I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: TweenMax is not defined

...

Why cant i use the libraries in functions.js ? i'm confused.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't work because of how [vue and webpack handle assets and static files](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html).

Usually you would just install your module via npm like:

`npm install gsap --save`

That's for TweenMax you tried to use. You'll find it [on npm here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gsap).

Then in the .vue file where you want to use it, you would just import and use it:

```
<script>
 import {TweenMax} from 'gsap'
 export default {
   methods: {
     myMethod () {
       TweenMax.to()
     }
   }
 }
</script>
```

If you want to use them in several components you could consider [adding them as instance properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html). Then you don't have to import them manually all the time.